# How to query paper entity data by DOI in MAG-Academic Knowledge API(cognitive service)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

How to extract the paper data by querying DOI as a parameter, in GET/POST request URL.

Basically, I tried with by querying paper Id as a parameter. Please refer my sample code as followed.

https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(Id=2153635508)&model=latest&count=50&offset=0&attributes=Ti,E.DOI

I am getting the output as-
{"expr": "And(Id=2153635508)","entities":[{"logprob": -13.241,"prob": 1.7762609374E-06,"Id": 2153635508,"Ti": "libsvm a library for support vector machines","DOI": "10.1145/1961189.1961199","PK": 2153635508}]}

Basically, I want the same output by the help of DOI instead of Id in the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `expr`-field should be `DOI='{DOI}'`, for example:

```
https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?&expr=DOI=%2710.1145/2883851.2883895%27&count=10&attributes=AA.AuN,AA.AuId,Ti,VFN,Y&orderby=Y:desc&subscription-key={YOUR-KEY}
```

You can change the `attributes` field to get the data you need.